# How to accept the bluetooth pair request through terminal without GUI

Tags: terminal, raspberry-pi, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

When i send a bluetooth pair request to raspberry pi , it asking to confirm acceptance in GUI, i wish to give the confirmation through terminal without GUI, How should i do this
i tried with NoInputNoOutput agent and given the below commands, it's pairing successfully but not conected to audio

pair xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
trust xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
connect xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

how to accept the access through terminal

[image: Bluetooth Authentication request]

[image: Authorization request]